# Can I highlight selected text, store it in a string, and replay it later?

Tags: javascript

I am using window.getSelection and designmode to highlight text on a page.
Is it possible to store it somehow as a string so I can save it and replay it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

> In JavaScript, when an object is passed to a function expecting a string (like [window.alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/alert) or [document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/write)), the object's [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method is called and the returned value is passed to the function. This can make the object appear to be a string when used with other functions when it is really an object with properties and methods.
>   [...]
>   However, attempting to use a JavaScript [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) property or method such as [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) or [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) directly on a [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object will result in an error if it does not have that property or method and may return unexpected results if it does. To use a Selection object as a string, call its toString() method directly

```js
var selObj, range;
document.onmouseup = function() {
  selObj = window.getSelection();
  if (selObj.isCollapsed) return;
  range = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
}

function replay() {
  selObj.removeAllRanges();
  selObj.addRange(range);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="replay()">replay</button>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus commodo mauris quis est auctor faucibus. Curabitur lacus libero, sagittis a augue sed, viverra condimentum enim. Nam euismod lorem dui, vestibulum vulputate tellus euismod eget. Vestibulum
  ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce cursus dui in nisi egestas, at maximus mauris ultricies. Vivamus velit eros, imperdiet a mollis non, fringilla at nisl. Aliquam tempus interdum efficitur. Praesent id
  ex tempor, tristique mi non, blandit quam. Pellentesque non dignissim nulla, vitae finibus nunc.
</p>
<p>
  Sed commodo sagittis lacus a iaculis. Maecenas cursus tincidunt dolor, vel egestas ante euismod nec. Vestibulum lacinia mi vitae lacus aliquet, id porta metus posuere. Phasellus hendrerit vehicula ligula, sed dignissim orci accumsan sit amet. Proin at
  dictum dui. Nulla facilisi. Sed velit purus, lobortis eget turpis at, pellentesque eleifend magna. Morbi sed nunc blandit, mollis velit nec, ultrices mauris. Pellentesque augue dolor, malesuada id vulputate at, efficitur lacinia orci.
</p>
<p>
  Nullam vitae leo condimentum, finibus nulla id, lobortis magna. Nulla id tellus elementum, fermentum erat a, venenatis lectus. Vivamus congue lobortis est at feugiat. Aliquam rutrum efficitur ornare. Mauris molestie porta augue, vel semper erat aliquet
  vitae. Suspendisse id libero aliquam, lacinia felis nec, elementum ex. Aliquam erat volutpat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc sem mi, egestas at ipsum ut, vehicula egestas lorem. Morbi
  fringilla sit amet lacus eget rhoncus. Fusce consectetur eu ex vitae rhoncus. Aenean rutrum eros sit amet hendrerit ullamcorper.
</p>
<p>
  Nam laoreet magna vehicula convallis maximus. Phasellus id purus eleifend, tincidunt nibh at, molestie mauris. Nam eget consequat velit. Duis non neque tempor, porttitor enim accumsan, gravida velit. In arcu purus, sollicitudin quis fringilla ut, blandit
  sed odio. Donec id felis metus. Vestibulum vel quam sodales, pharetra ipsum eget, tincidunt justo. Cras vitae tortor non enim iaculis gravida a sed velit. Vestibulum augue nulla, commodo quis erat quis, auctor placerat eros.
</p>
<p>
  Cras hendrerit orci nunc. Vestibulum mollis libero vitae libero rutrum viverra. Praesent et varius eros, vel accumsan ante. Nulla rhoncus, nisl a lobortis mollis, ante massa pharetra sapien, ut congue tellus ligula at turpis. Vestibulum sodales, tortor
  dictum dictum finibus, mauris orci pharetra justo, at eleifend massa metus vitae urna. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc cursus urna ac lacus lacinia ultricies. Donec blandit elit eu ante
  tempor, vitae vestibulum enim sodales. Aenean bibendum purus ut venenatis tristique. Nulla convallis, ipsum ut iaculis efficitur, ipsum risus maximus nibh, eu cursus orci tortor at ligula. Curabitur et est et erat eleifend posuere vel ac nisi. In in
  lectus ligula.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Sounds like it is not possible then.

Comment: well yes, if you only want its string value, just store your selection's `object.toString()` in a variable. (still from the same page : `var selectedText = selObj.toString();`)

Comment: I want more than the string value.  I want to be able to store the attributes so I can replay it later.

Comment: Please provide a snippet with what you really want to "replay". If you need to store the whole object, then just store it in a variable (selObj in mdn's example)

Comment: @SteveLloyd Ok, I give you one in the answer

Comment: @SteveLloyd did this solved your problem? If so, consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). (Valid for all your other answered questions)